# What's the impact of the negative bottom margin

Tags: css, margin

First, here is the html:

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="second">
        <div class="third">
           Hello, margin collapsing!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then here is the CSS:

```
.first {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

.second {
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.third {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

In the final layout, the third div looks like it doesn't have the bottom margin. I know it must be the effect of the second div whose bottom margin is negative. But I don't understand how it works. Could you please provide an explanation?

Comment: on block elements you can use negative margins. first is padded, second in it, so still here this is ok. in the second you set a negative margin, and in third you add that so it is totally unnecessary.  Check what happens when you add 30 to third: https://jsfiddle.net/sm4Lf591/

Comment: The text content of your example mentions the answer already -
 collapsing margins. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: You should look up "margin collapsing". Very informative.

Answer (score 1):

**Padding** - Creates, easy said, a invisible border inside your element. You provide with it the spaces inside of your element (arround the content).

```
.first {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

So here you tell, any content of first hast to be 20px away from each side (each side cause you did not provide any declaration like padding-top)

**Margin** - On the other hand creates the opposite, it creates space arround your element.

```
.second {
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

So this one says the second block has a space on the bottom outside. Its defined negative, which means the following items float in your element.

This explains it awfully: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model